# Is it possible to initialize Shiny input values without including them in the ui?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

I'm building a Shiny app where elements of the output can be clicked to set input variables. I'm doing so by including some Javascript that calls the `Shiny.setInputValue` method.

I'd like to initialize these values but don't want the user to be aware of them, since they're only used behind the scenes. My current hack is to use the `hidden` function from the `shinyjs` library around some buttons in the ui, but that's not very satisfying. Here's an example of my approach:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  hidden(
    numericInput(label = NULL, inputId = 'INPUT', value = 0)
  ),
  DT::dataTableOutput("one_row")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  script <- 'Shiny.setInputValue("INPUT", Math.random());'
  btn <- as.character(actionButton(inputId = 'button', 
                                   label = "Click me!", 
                                   onclick = script))
  one_row <- iris[1, ] %>% mutate(button = btn)
  output$one_row <- DT::renderDataTable({
    print(input$INPUT)
    one_row}, escape = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So my main question is: is there a better way to set the default of these "invisible" inputs? Should I just use the `runjs` function somewhere in the app?

A related question is: is it possible to access these input values using javascript? I was hoping there was something like `Shiny.getInputValue` but there doesn't seem to be.

EDIT:

Here's a more thorough example that shows precisely what I'm trying to do. I'm using`visNetwork`, but I'd like to override some of the default behavior. Usually, when you click on a node it shows all connected edges, incoming or outgoing.

I'd like a node selection to show only edges in one direction, and then to show the other direction if you click again (in, out, in, out, ...). To do so, I need to keep track of clicks (`click`), which node is selected (`selected_node`), and what direction to currently show (`out`).

To accomplish this, I'm currently using `visEvents` to redefine what happens on a click and `visNetworkProxy` to select nodes and edges based on that click.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(tidyverse)
library(visNetwork)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  hidden(
    numericInput(label = NULL, inputId = 'click', value = 0),
    numericInput(label = NULL, inputId = 'selected_node', value = 0)
  ),
  visNetworkOutput("network")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  network <- reactive({
    nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3)
    edges <- data.frame(expand.grid(to = 1:3, from = 1:3)) %>%
      mutate(id = row_number())
    list(nodes = nodes, edges = edges)
    })

  output$network <- renderVisNetwork({

    network <- network()

    visNetwork(network$nodes, network$edges) %>% 
      visPhysics(enabled = FALSE) %>%
      visLayout(randomSeed = 123) %>%
      visEdges(smooth = list(type = 'curvedCW'),
               arrows =list(to = list(enabled = TRUE, scaleFactor = 0.5))) %>% 
      visEvents(type = "on", 
                click = "function (properties) {
                          var nodeID = properties.nodes[0]
                          var edgeID = properties.edges[0];
                          if (nodeID) { Shiny.onInputChange('click', 1, {priority: \"event\"});
                                        Shiny.onInputChange('selected_node', nodeID)} 
                          else if (edgeID){ Shiny.onInputChange('click', 2);}
                          else { Shiny.onInputChange('click', 3);}}")
  })

  out <- FALSE

  observe({
    out <<- !out
    nodeID <- input$selected_node
    network <- network()

    # only fire if node was selected
    if(input$click == 1){
      edgeIDs <- network$edges %>% filter(to == nodeID) %>%
        pull(id)

      if(out){edgeIDs <- network$edges %>% filter(from == input$selected_node) %>% pull(id)}

      visNetworkProxy("network") %>%
        visSetSelection(nodesId = nodeID, edgesId = edgeIDs, highlightEdges = FALSE)
    }
  })
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You don't need the `numericInput` if you run `Shiny.setInputValue`.

Comment: what exactly do you use these hidden inputs for? If you want to have dynamic values that are not visible on the ui (and can trigger events), `reactiveValues()` come to mind,...

Comment: @BigDataScientist the inputs turn on certain visualization options. can `reactiveValues` be accessed/changed via `Shiny.setInputValue` as well? Or are they a different class entirely?

Comment: again, i think it would be good to show what your final goal is. `shiny.setInputValue` is a tool and i dont see why one would need it when using reactiveValues,...

Comment: To you're related question: You dont need `Shiny.getInputValue`, you can just use `INPUT.value`.